# Error Parsing File:LazyUserDataModel.java on Simtay SimpleCRUD

Tags: java, primefaces, netbeans-8

I recently downloaded this [SimpleCRUD](https://github.com/Simtay/SimpleCRUD)  application by Simtay. I loaded the project on Netbeans 8.0.1 and added the necessary libraries. I get this error:

> @Override
>       public List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) on the class
>
> LazyUserDataModel.java

Below is the class.

```
package com.nz.simplecrud.controller;


import com.nz.simplecrud.entity.User;
import com.nz.simplecrud.service.DataAccessService;
import com.nz.simplecrud.util.LazySorter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

/**
 * 
 * Custom Lazy User DataModel which extends PrimeFaces LazyDataModel.
 * For more information please visit http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableLazy.jsf
 */

public class LazyUserDataModel extends LazyDataModel<User> implements Serializable{

    // Data Source for binding data to the DataTable
    private List<User> datasource;
    // Selected Page size in the DataTable
    private int pageSize;
    // Current row index number
    private int rowIndex;
    // Total row number
    private int rowCount;
    // Data Access Service for create read update delete operations
    private DataAccessService crudService;

    /**
     *
     * @param crudService
     */
    public LazyUserDataModel(DataAccessService crudService) {
        this.crudService = crudService;
    }

    /**
     * Lazy loading user list with sorting ability
     * @param first
     * @param pageSize
     * @param sortField
     * @param sortOrder
     * @param filters
     * @return List<User>
     */ 
    @Override
    public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
        datasource = crudService.findWithNamedQuery(User.ALL, first, first + pageSize);
        // if sort field is not null then we sort the field according to sortfield and sortOrder parameter
        if(sortField != null) {  
            Collections.sort(datasource, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));  
        } 
        setRowCount(crudService.countTotalRecord(User.TOTAL));   
        return datasource;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the row is available
     * @return boolean
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        if(datasource == null) 
            return false;
        int index = rowIndex % pageSize ; 
        return index >= 0 && index < datasource.size();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user object's primary key
     * @param user
     * @return Object
     */
    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(User user) {
        return user.getId().toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the user object at the specified position in datasource.
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public User getRowData() {
        if(datasource == null)
            return null;
        int index =  rowIndex % pageSize;
        if(index > datasource.size()){
            return null;
        }
        return datasource.get(index);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the user object that has the row key.
     * @param rowKey
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public User getRowData(String rowKey) {
        if(datasource == null)
            return null;
       for(User user : datasource) {  
           if(user.getId().toString().equals(rowKey))  
           return user;  
       }  
       return null;  
    }


    /*
     * ===== Getters and Setters of LazyUserDataModel fields
     */


    /**
     *
     * @param pageSize
     */
    @Override
    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    /**
     * Returns page size
     * @return int
     */
    @Override
    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    /**
     * Returns current row index
     * @return int
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowIndex() {
        return this.rowIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Sets row index
     * @param rowIndex
     */
    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Sets row count
     * @param rowCount
     */
    @Override
    public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns row count
     * @return int
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets wrapped data
     * @param list
     */
    @Override
    public void setWrappedData(Object list) {
        this.datasource = (List<User>) list;
    }

    /**
     * Returns wrapped data
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object getWrappedData() {
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

Any help please??

Comment: Which version of Primefaces you are using?

Comment: Are you trying to add method public List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) to your class ?

Comment: @Unknown i am running pf 5. I am actually trying to run the project as it is. I haven't added any method yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules for overriding

> The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the overridden
>   method. The return type should be the same or a subtype of the return
>   type declared in the original overridden method in the super class.

[LazyDataModel](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html) class has the method called load (Primefaces 5)

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
 }
```

You can only Override the above method in LazyUserDataModel if you are using Primefaces 5.

Since the method

```
load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters)
```

does not present in the `LazyDataModel` (PF5) it is normal to have the error.

So how to resolve?

Change `Map<String,String> filters` to  `Map<String, Object> filters` (In order to override need to have Same Signature)

Note: Simtay project was written using PF3.4, with [LazyDataModel](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html).

Comment: I will try implementing your idea and I hope it will solve my headache